# rdesktop for windows?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdesktop

I'm looking for a good RDP client for Windows. The built-in one for WinXP doesn't do sound and puts black padding around the window for some reason.

Something like rdesktop would be perfect. I've tried getting it to run on windows, but I've run into problems. Even though I had XminG running as an xserver, it said it couldn't connect to the local display. Eventually I installed x/cygwin and compiled rdesktop myself, and that ended up working, but the sound still didn't work.

Is there any good rdesktop-like client for windows, or a stand-alone version that wouldn't require installing x/cygwin and compiling just to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [Microsoft Remote Desktop client 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925876). It is newer than the one that ships with XP.

Comment: i think i already have it, since it said i don't need to install the update

Comment: Version 7.0 is the latest version, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084. Btw, RDP is able to redirect sound at least since version 5.0 already, you probably simply haven't configured it to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Søren Schimkat has [a post](http://www.soren.schimkat.dk/Blog/?p=69) on his blog.

The prebuilt binary Cygwin versions are available here:
http://www.soren.schimkat.dk/Downloads/

You will need a Microsoft Windows compatible  Xfree/X Window server such as Xming, MobaXterm or [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/files/)

Answer (score 0):

[Win32 RDesktop](http://40in.spb.ru/rdesktop_win32/) may be what you want.  This was linked from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rdesktop).

Comment: i tried running this, but it says that it can't connect to the display

Comment: i even tried running it from within an xterm when i did "startxwin" from cygwin, and it says it can't open the display 6 times instead of just once.